# Deploying self contained Perl 6 script

Tags: raku

What is the best strategy to deploy a Perl 6 script which use external modules like `LWP::Simple`?

For example in Perl we have `PAR`. Is there are an option in Perl 6 to deploy a self contained script that the user need only to run without bothering himself with installing Rakudo and external Perl 6 modules?

Answer (score 8):

You can create a .jar file and then use java to execute the code. From there, there are plenty of tools to convert a .jar into a binary file (or .exe in Windows).

The syntax for that is:

```
perl6 --target=jvm  --output=your_file.jar your_file.pl6
```

If that script were the trivial

```
say "this is running as a .jar file"
```

You should be able to run `java -jar your_file.jar` and get

```
this is running as a .jar file
```

On macOS, there is a bit of a wrinkle since this feature requires you to build perl6 (Rakudo Star) with Java 1.7+ instead of the Mac's system Java. For this reason the version on your system may not have shipped with JVM support.

If you're using `homebrew`, here's what you do to fix that:

1. `brew uninstall perl6`
2. `brew tap homebrew/versions` (so you can install Java 1.7)
3. `brew install Caskroom/versions/java7` (install Java 1.7)
4. optionally: open a new tab in terminal (you only need to do this if, for some reason, you get an error that Java 1.6 is still in use. )
5. `brew install perl6 --with-jvm` (build `perl6` with Java Virtual Machine support)

Comment: Here are some developments a few years later (2013→2016): there was [an NQP tool to do this](http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl6-compiler/13740/) but I'm not sure that it's working. It is possible today to run Perl 6 in the JVM (when Rakudo is complied with the JVM backend), but I'm not sure if it is presently possible to create a standalone JAR.